# Blank Space left on the last page of google docs

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I get how much blank space is left on the last page of google docs using appscript?

I tried this but it does not return the blank space of last page.

```
function margin(doc_body)

{
  var margin_top =  doc_body.getMarginTop()
  var margin_bottom =  doc_body.getMarginBottom()
  var pageHeight =  doc_body.getPageHeight() - margin_top - margin_bottom;
  return pageHeight
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not the blank space?  There are 72 points per inch.  An 8.5x11 page has a page height of 792 points.  Minus your margins will give you the blank space height.  If there is some text on the last page do you want to know how much space is left excluding the text?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to know how much space is left excluding the text on the last page.

Comment: Unfortunately only hard page breaks can be detected.  The page break caused by text rolling to the next page are not detectable.  So if the last paragraph of your doc rolls to the last page, there is no way of determining how much of it is on that page.